# Saving relation JPA with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I'm doing a registration and I have the fields

- Nome:
- Data de Nascimento:
- Inscrição Estadual:
- Nome Responsável:
- CPF Responsável:
- Cep:
- Bloco:
- Número:

  when i saving, I can not write data from the PessoasEnderecos class, the other data is recording normal. I'm getting all the data on the screen so much that I debugged the browser to see ..

It shows no error. Does anyone know what I'm missing ??

my class Pacientes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pacientes", schema = "sau")
public class Pacientes implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5776384003601026304L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idPaciente")
    private Long idPaciente;


    @JoinColumn(name="idPessoa")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Pessoas pessoa;


    @Column(name = "nomeResponsavel")
    private String nomeResponsavel;


    @Column(name = "cpfResponsavel")
    private String cpfResponsavel;

    public Pacientes() {
    }
    //gets and sets
    }
```

my class Pessoas

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoas", schema="glb")
public class Pessoas implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4042023941980758267L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Long idPessoa;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataNascimento;   

    private String inscricaoEstadual;   

    private String inscricaoMunicipal;    

    private String nome;

    public Pessoas() {
    }
  //gets and sets

} 

@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoas_enderecos" ,schema="glb")
public class PessoasEnderecos implements Serializable  {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2560542418318988673L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPessoaEndereco;

    private String bloco;

    private String cep;

    private String numero;

    @JoinColumn(name="idPessoa")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Pessoas pessoa;



    public PessoasEnderecos() {
    }

//gets and sets

}
```

my methods

class Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/pacientes")
    public Pacientes cadastrarPacientes(@RequestBody Pacientes pac) {    
        return pacientesService.cadastrar(pac);
    }
```

class service

```
public Pacientes cadastrar(Pacientes pacientes){        
        return pacRepository.save(pacientes);       
    }
```

class repository

```
public interface PacientesRepository extends JpaRepository<Pacientes, Integer> {


}
```

Comment: You save the object `Pacientes`. But I cannot see any linkage between this class and `PessoasEnderecos` in your code.

Comment: @sergey  well.. in my entity `PessoasEnderecos` i have this relation `@JoinColumn(name="idPessoa")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Pessoas pessoa;`

Answer (score 0):

You should also add the linkage `@OneToMany` in `Pacientes`:

```
public class Pacientes implements Serializable {
...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "pessoa")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private List<PessoasEnderecos> pessoasEnderecos = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Update:**

```
and your JSON should be something like this:

{
  "nomeResponsavel": "abc",
  "pessoasEnderecos": [
    {
      "bloco": "sdds",
      "cep": "sdasdsad",
      "numero": "sdasdsa"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i try to implement you sugestion but i got a error when i try to save.. `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token`